# Homepage showing correct domain rest of the site isn't

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns

I just started hosting a wordpress blog on Azure. I'm using a DNS other than Azure. I've configured it to point mysite.com to mysite.azurewebsites.net The site is up and running, the only problem is that when i navigate beyond the homepage the url changes from mysite.com mystic.azurewebsites.net/somepage/

Answer (score 1):

You could follow [Configuring a custom domain name for an Azure cloud service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) and [How to Redirect Your Domain or SubDomain to Your Windows Azure Website](https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/how-to-redirect-your-domain-or-subdomain-to-windows-azure-website/) to redirect your domain.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with Wordpress settings not my DNS settings.